# Visual Studio Community 2015 MFC empty project doesn't compile

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2015

I just installed Visual Studio Community 2015 (version 14.0.24720.00) and tried to create an MFC dialog based project. 
In the wizard I only selected "Dialog based", leaving all the other settings to default.

The project simply doesn't compile, which isn't exactly a promising starting point...

Am I overlooking something? Is the MFC template broken?

Below, the compile time errors I get (I cut away the long paths for the sake of legibility).

Thanks for your time.

```
program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.01>------ Build started: Project: MFCApplication, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

1>  stdafx.cpp

1>c:\[...omissis...]\atlcore.h(639): error C2065: 'LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\uianimation.h(2621): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxanimationhelper.h(411): error C2065: 'UI_E_VALUE_NOT_SET': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxanimationhelper.h(441): error C2065: 'UI_E_VALUE_NOT_SET': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2103): error C3646: 'm_pConfigs': unknown override specifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2103): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2024): error C2065: 'GC_PAN_WITH_GUTTER': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2024): error C2065: 'GC_PAN_WITH_INERTIA': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2088): error C2065: 'GC_ALLGESTURES': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2030): error C2065: 'GID_ZOOM': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2030): error C2065: 'GC_ZOOM': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2036): error C2065: 'GID_ROTATE': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2036): error C2065: 'GC_ROTATE': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2042): error C2065: 'GID_TWOFINGERTAP': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2042): error C2065: 'GC_TWOFINGERTAP': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2056): error C2065: 'GID_PAN': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2056): error C2065: 'GC_PAN': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2062): error C2065: 'GID_PAN': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2062): error C2065: 'GC_PAN_WITH_SINGLE_FINGER_VERTICALLY': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2068): error C2065: 'GID_PAN': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2068): error C2065: 'GC_PAN_WITH_SINGLE_FINGER_HORIZONTALLY': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2074): error C2065: 'GID_PAN': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxw
in.h(2074): error C2065: 'GC_PAN_WITH_GUTTER': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2080): error C2065: 'GID_PAN': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2080): error C2065: 'GC_PAN_WITH_INERTIA': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2964): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2964): error C3646: 'GetCurrentGestureInfo': unknown override specifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2964): error C2059: syntax error: ')'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(2965): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(3020): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PTOUCHINPUT'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(3030): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PTOUCHINPUT'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(3043): error C3646: 'm_pCurrentGestureInfo': unknown override specifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(3043): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(4141): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'TBPFLAG'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(5447): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(5447): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxwin.h(5447): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxglobals.h(315): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxglobals.h(315): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxglobals.h(315): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxadv.h(244): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxadv.h(244): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxadv.h(245): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxadv.h(314): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'KNOWNDESTCATEGORY'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxadv.h(390): error C2065: 'ICustomDestinationList': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxadv.h(390): error C2923: 'ATL::CComPtr': 'ICustomDestinationList' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxadv.h(273): error C2039: 'AbortList': is not a member of 'ATL::_NoAddRefReleaseOnCComPtr<T>'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxadv.h(428): error C2065: 'IApplicationDestinations': undeclared identifier

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxadv.h(428): error C2923: 'ATL::CComPtr': 'IApplicationDestinations' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'

1>c:\[...omissis...]\afxadv.h(430): warning C4624: 'CAppDestinations': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: The first error is in the line `return(::LoadLibraryExW(pszLibrary, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32));`, that is conditionally excluded for me by `#if (_ATL_NTDDI_MIN > NTDDI_WIN7)` in the line above... Anyway, that constant is defined in `libloaderapi.h`, found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um` on my system. do you have that file (I guess you do, or the error would be different)? Where?

Comment: Hi Vlad. 
Yes, I have that file on my system, and that folder is in the "include directories" (Evaluated values) for this project.
I see the definition at line 410

#define LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32        0x00000800

Something's wrong in VS configuration I think (I used VS2009 since yesterday :( )

Thanks for your time

Comment: It seems to be a problem inherited from the VS2008 settings...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Visual studio 2015 inherited the Visual Studio 2009 settings.
Removing the include folder

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include

everything started to work normally

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem bringing 2010 forward to 2015. Tracked the problem down to the targetver.h file. It was defining older versions of windows. Replaced all previous defines with the current default.

```
target.h
   // delete everything here
   #include <SDKDDKVer.h>

-- end of target.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you to fix your problem.
In Visual Studio 2015, C++ tooling is no longer installed by default.  Instead, the C++ compiler, libraries, and project templates have been moved into an optional feature. Upon launching setup, you can choose a “Typical” or “Custom” install;
If you choose “Typical”, then you can’t use Visual Studio to develop in C++, because only managed languages and web development tools will be installed. 
[Setup Changes in Visual Studio 2015 Affecting C++ Developers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/)